# access design view freezes with SQL 'OR' statement

Tags: sql, filter

Ii'm using this SQL statement in access to filter data, it works well, only problem is that "Or" statement causes complete crash of design view of query and therefore  whole access.

I have approx. 70 columns in table. design view of query works if I use it on 4-5 columns, but if I put it on more columns, or all of them, it crashes. I noticed access automatically adds criteria in columns in design view. Any idea why is it like this? Everything is working OK until i try to view query in design view.

```
WHERE ((table.[column]) Like [Forms]![form]![combo-box] Or [Forms]![form]![combo-box] Is Null) 
AND ((table.[column2]) Like [Forms]![form]![combo-box2] Or [Forms]![form]![combo-box2] Is Null) AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
WHERE (
          (
                ( [Forms]![form]![combo-box] Is Not Null )
            AND ( table.[column] Like [Forms]![form]![combo-box] )
          )
       Or ( [Forms]![form]![combo-box] Is Null )
      )
  AND (
          (
                ( [Forms]![form]![combo-box2] Is Not Null )
            AND ( table.[column2] Like [Forms]![form]![combo-box2] )
          )
       Or ( [Forms]![form]![combo-box2] Is Null )
      )
  AND ...
```